# need help solving this resource allocation problem

Tags: resources, allocation

I am looking to optimally solve a simple resource allocation problem that has a set of tasks and a set of men as its input. Can anyone please suggest some textbooks that would give me a clear idea and to refer from?

I am new to research and I am looking to learn about the resource allocation problem and the algorithmic ways to solve them. I have tried looking for them but my efforts were in vain.